# "Ta[b]g" instead of "tag" typo on profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, suggested-edits

There's a typo in profile page, more precisely at:

```
Profile -> Activity -> Suggestions
```

history ribbon: when I've suggested "Go" tag edit. Here's how it looks like:

[image: tabg typo bug example]

Comment: Conbfirmed.​​​​

Comment: Same here but I liek teh tabg better.

Comment: Is this a clbuttic error? ;-) --- And before you say it: I know it's not!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will be fibxed in the next deploy.

Comment: +1 just for the humour. =]